# unix command to search text and copy full XML

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

Using UNIX,

My log file contains multiple XML. How I can search with UNIX command or script, so I can get all XML which hold contain abc?

For example, below log file holds 4 XMLs. I want to create one new file which hold all XML which contain `**<value>abc</value>**`

```
<createR>            <----- this is starting tag of XML
<value>abc</value>   <----- search for this value
<val>xyz</val>
</createR>           <----- this is end tag of XML

<createR>
<value>123</value>
<val>xyz</val>
</createR>

<createR>
<value>abc</value>
<val>xyz</val>
</createR>

<createR>
<value>qpw</value>
<val>xyz</val>
</createR>
```

Desire out put in new file

```
<createR>
<value>abc</value>
<val>xyz</val>
</createR>

<createR>
<value>abc</value>
<val>xyz</val>
</createR>
```

I am trying with grep but only getting 2 line NOT full XML. XML start tag is `<createR>` and END tag `</createR>`.

There might be change that, all these XML may get logged in one single line.

Answer (score 2):

```
 awk 'BEGIN{RS=""; FS="\n"}/abc/{print $0 "\n"}' sample.csv
```

Use `\n` as field separator and "" as record separator, it will treat each chunk as one line, then `/abc/` will check each line matches the abc pattern or not, if it matches, print it out
Output:

```
<createR>
<value>abc</value>
<val>xyz</val>
</createR>

<createR>
<value>abc</value>
<val>xyz</val>
</createR>
```

Comment: what if, there is not line break. there is possibility that all XML might get logged in one single line.

Comment: fresher: could you please let me know if you have tried my command. 

Also Haifeng has given solution(nice one) as per your sample shown if you have any conditions could add into your post.

Comment: @fresher that's quit easy to achive if there's no space but you want it: `sed   's@</createR>@</createR>\n@' sample.csv`. just need to replace the end createR tag with newline character behind it

Comment: i mean newline not space

Comment: I tried, sed one ...but sir not helping. if there is line break your above awk command works, but suppose, I log is single line log file, then how to get this... pls help

Comment: @fresher `sed s@</createR>@</createR>\n@' no-linebreak-file.csv > linebreak-file.csv` then run the awk command on `linebreak-file.csv`

Comment: no sir, cannot create new log file... it's too big and its logging too many other things...

Comment: you can use `sed -i 's@</createR>@</createR>\n@' sample.csv`  it will modify sample.csv directly, but this command is not recommended

Answer (score 1):

@fresher: Try:

```
awk '/<\/createR>/{A="";if(P){print Q ORS $0};Q=P=""} /<createR>/{A=1} A{Q=Q?Q ORS $0:$0;if($0 ~ /<value>abc<\/value>/){P=1}}'   Input_file
```

In case it is in complete line you could try following then.

```
 awk '/<\/createR>/{A="";if(P){print Q ORS $0};Q=P=""} /<createR>/{A=1} A{Q=Q?Q ORS $0:$0;if($0 ~ /<value>abc<\/value>/){P=1}}' RS=" "   Input_file
```

Will add explanation shortly.

**EDIT:** as mentioned following is the explanation on same.

```
awk 
'/<\/createR>/                ##### Searching for string "</createR>" here.
                              ##### If above condition is TRUE then execute all following statements.
{A="";                        ##### Nullify the variable A's value, will explain A's existence in next steps.
if(P){                        ##### If variable P's value exist then do following.
print Q ORS $0};              ##### print the value of variable Q then ORS(Output record separator) then $0(current line)'s values.
Q=P=""}                       ##### Nullifying the values of variables Q and P now.
/<createR>/                   ##### Searching for string "<createR>" here.
{A=1}                         ##### Set the value of variable A to 1.
A{                            ##### If variable A's value is 1 then do following.
Q=Q?Q ORS $0:$0;              ##### creating a variable named Q whose value will be appended with values of current lines with ORS.
if($0 ~ /<value>abc<\/value>/)##### checking if current line's value has abc in it as per OP's request. If yes then 
{P=1}                         ##### Set the variable named P's value to 1.
}'
```

Comment: thanks, but what if, there is not line break. there is possibility that all XML might get logged in one single line.

Comment: Will there be space if a new line is not there in Input_file ?

Comment: fresher, kindly check my added 2nd one now and let me know how it goes then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 +1 for you because of the great explanation!

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: its return 4 XML in 4 lines. It should be either 1 or 2 line.

Answer (score 0):

If this isn't all you need:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/abc/' file
<createR>            <----- this is starting tag of XML
<value>abc</value>   <----- search for this value
<val>xyz</val>
</createR>           <----- this is end tag of XML

<createR>
<value>abc</value>
<val>xyz</val>
</createR>
```

then edit your question to show more truly representative sample input/output that we could actually test a potential solution against to learn if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use an XML-aware tool for jobs like this:

```
 xmlstarlet sel -t -c "//value[text()='abc']/.." input.xml
```